# find subarrays with the same sum and in same length

Tags: algorithm

suppose there are two arrays in same length [an] and [bn],find if there are two sub arrays of [an] and [bn], so that the sub arrays have the same sum and in the same length. For example: [an] = [5,4,17,10,29], [bn]=[1,22,23,4,15], the program will return "yes" because [17,10] in [an] and [23,4] in [bn] have the same sum and in the same length. Is there any algorithm better than O(n^3)?

Comment: Yes, it can be done in O(n^2)

Comment: with o(nlogn) with additional storage of o(n)

Answer (score 1):

(Well, if I point out an O(n^2) version perhaps I'll learn from somebody that does better). Suppose that for each array you compute the sum of the first k elements, for all k = 1 to length of array, so that [5,4,17,10,29] turns into [5,9,26,36,65]. You can obviously do this in O(n) just by keeping a running total.

Now you can work out the sum of any section of that array by subtracting one running total from another, so e.g. 17 + 10 = 36 - 9. So you can work out the O(n^2) sums of all contiguous sub-arrays in time O(n^2). Enter the results for one sub-array into a hash table and then compute all the results for the other sub-array and check to see if they are in the hash table. Hash table operations are (probabalisticaly) O(1) so the total cost is O(n^2)

Comment: Because `the sub arrays have the same sum and in the same length`, I believe the hash table is containing custom class as key?

Comment: This puts an upper bound on the average case to O(n^2), and using a BST limits the worst case to O(n^2 log n). The problem is that both solutions use O(n^2) additional space.

Comment: I doubt that anyone will improve on n^2 by more than log factors -- I believe that there's a reduction from this problem to the problem of finding a 3-term arithmetic progression, which has no faster known algorithm under mild assumptions about the representation of the input.

Comment: @Pham Trung - the hash table only requires integers as keys (the difference of two partial sums) so you shouldn't need a custom class

Comment: @David Eisenstat Thanks for that. I have provided another answer for amusement, which violates the standard assumptions. It would be nice if somebody came up with a breakthrough answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a comedy answer, with cost n log n, *for suitably defined n*. As in my previous answer, we turn the input data into partial sums, leaving us the problem of finding positions within the partial sums denoting values that obey A - B = C - D.

Now let's assume that the numbers in the arrays are small integers, and let n be the largest sum in either array. For each side, create an array of length n, with all values 0, except at positions i where i is a partial sum, which you can set to 1. Using the FFT, compute the convolution of each array with itself, in time O(n log n). We now have two arrays of length O(n) (some padding will be required) with non-zero values at offsets corresponding to the subtraction of two partial sums - so all we have to do is scan both arrays to find any position which has non-zero values in both arrays of size O(n)